# He is just working at his English

Tags: phrases

Could you help me to understand whether this phrase is idiomatic or it's bad English, especially the second sentence? If it's not so good, please write your version in common English.

> Don’t disturb him. He is just working at his English.

Comment: _Don't disturb him. He is working on his English._ 'at his English' is incorrect.

Comment: I disagree. I think "working at his English" is also acceptable.